# CGAffineTransformScale in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, cgaffinetransform, gestures

Swift 3.0 does not have a method called `CGAffineTransformScale`.

```
func didPinchGesture(pinchRecognizer : UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
  if let view = pinchRecognizer.view {
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform,
                            recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale)
    pinchRecognizer.scale = 1
  }
}
```

`scaleBy` does not autocomplete but added to `CGAffineTransform` `scaleBy` throws error, since `scale` is not a property of CGAffineTransform anymore:
`CGAffineTransform.scaledBy(view.transform, pinchRecognizer.scale, pinchRecognizer.scale)`.

What is the best way to configure the pinch gesture recognizer with Swift 3.0?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Swift, [`CGAffineTransformScale`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1455882-cgaffinetransformscale?language=objc) is imported as an instance method on the [`CGAffineTransform`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform) struct, called [`scaledBy(x:y:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform/1455882-scaledby):

```
view.transform = view.transform.scaledBy(x: recognizer.scale, y: recognizer.scale)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Alexander. Is there anything in my questions that I should write to make it better?

Comment: @Eric Not really, but it would be good to be a bit more diligent about googling this stuff before answering. A lot of Cocoa APIs were implemented as C structs (like `CGAffineTransform`), with a suite of global functions that act on them (like `CGAffineTransformScale`), because they offered faster performance than Objective C classes/instance methods. Swift supports structs natively, and support instance methods on structs, so such C APIs are imported as native Swift structs, and their corresponding global functions are imported as instance methods on those native Swift structs.

Comment: @Eric This is the case for many structs, like `CGAffineTransform`, `CGPoint`, `CGRect`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, @Alexander. I will definitely be more diligent about Googling in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a scale transform in Swift 3 like this:

```
if let view = pinchRecognizer.view {
    view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: recognizer.scale, y: recognizer.scale)
    ...
  }
```

Comment: That just makes a new transform altogether.